# Why `\n` not working in Python

Tags: bash, shell, cmd

I'm trying following example :

`python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1]" "test\ntest"`

Output :

```
test\ntest
```

But I want following

```
test 
test
```

Update 1#
As @devnull suggested can solve the problem if user itself pass the with `$` but how about python should take care of this ?

I've tried :

```
python -c "import sys; print '$' + sys.argv[1]" 'test\ntest'
```

but output :

```
$test\ntest
```

Comment: What shell are you using? This is not a python problem.

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.1.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As deed02392 mentioned, shell sends the characters literally, so python "escapes" the backslash internally. To see what I mean, try

```
python -c "import sys; print repr(sys.argv[1])" "test\ntest"
'test\\ntest'
```

To work around this, do:

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1].decode('string_escape')" "test\ntest"
test
test
```

Answer (score 4):

Tell the shell to pass what you want to see:

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1]" $'test\ntest'
```

This would produce:

```
test
test
```

The `$'string'` syntax is referred to as [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

---

Another way would be to tell the shell to interpret your *original* output:

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1]" 'test\ntest' | xargs -0 echo -en
```

This would also produce:

```
test
test
```

Comment: 1up..I was about to write this

Comment: @devnull could you please explain what is `$`

Comment: @RahulPatil It's referred to as ANSI-C quoting.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible, and was about to suggest `python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1].decode('string_escape')" "test\ntest"` instead.  Hats off to you sir, literally (hats come off 3rd jan).

Answer (score 0):

Your shell is sending the python script the two literal characters `\` and `n`.

Since you're on bash, I believe if you just press the actual return key after `"test` it will detect you're still entering an argument and let you continue with another `test"` and then pass this to python.

Comment: But I've program which takes command line input from user and it should be converted to new line, so how to do that without `Ctrl+D`